# setInterval goes faster each time JQuery Moblie

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, setinterval

I have created an setInterval that switch between different pictures in 3 seconds each time the problem is that each time I press on "Back" (on car_choose page) and press in, the setInterval goes like crazy eventhough I used clearInterval.

I'd be glad if someone could help me, thanks in advence.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css_style.css"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <script>
        i=1;
        function picTimer()
        {   
            var j=1;
            while(j<=5)
            {
                ($("#car"+j)).css('display','none');
                ($("#img"+j)).css('display','none');
                j++;
            }
                if(i>5)
                {
                    i=1;
                    ($("#car"+i)).css('display','block');
                    ($("#img"+i)).css('display','block');
                }
                else 
                {                       
                    ($("#car"+i)).css('display','block');
                    ($("#img"+i)).css('display','block');
                }
                i++;
            }


        $(document).on("pageshow","#homepage",function()
        {
            $("#trythisone").click(function() //case LocalStorage is null.
            {           
            if(localStorage.getItem("user") == null)
                return false;
            else //Display pictures.
            {           
                ($("#img1")).css('display','block'); //First picture
                ($("#car1")).css('display','block'); //First car text

                myInterval  = setInterval(function(){picTimer()},3000);             
            }
            });         
        }); 


        //Stop interval
        $(document).on("pagehide","#car_choose",function()
        {

            clearInterval(myInterval);
            setTimeout(picTimer,1);
            var removeit=1;
            while(removeit<=5)
            {
                ($("#car"+removeit)).css('display','none');
                ($("#img"+removeit)).css('display','none');
                removeit++;
            }           
        });
    </script>


    <body>
    <div id="homepage" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">
                <div id="main-content">         
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <li id="trythisone"><a href="#car_choose" data-transition="flip">Invite a car</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="car_choose" data-role="page"  data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back">
        <div id="carhead" data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Car Choose</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="anyClass">
                <ul>
                    <li id="img1" class="jpg_move"><img src="car_pics\car1.jpg" width="400" height="400"></li>
                    <li id="img2" class="jpg_move"><img src="car_pics\car2.jpg" width="400" height="400"></li>
                    <li id="img3" class="jpg_move"><img src="car_pics\car3.jpg" width="400" height="400"></li>
                    <li id="img4" class="jpg_move"><img src="car_pics\car4.jpg" width="400" height="400"></li>
                    <li id="img5" class="jpg_move"><img src="car_pics\car5.jpg" width="400" height="400"></li>
                    <p id="car1" class="carText">Super Nano,Model : 2013, Automatic Transmission</p>
                    <p id="car2" class="carText">Fashion Car 2,Model : 1980, Manual Transmission</p>
                    <p id="car3" class="carText">Fashion Car 3,Model : 1968, Manual Transmission</p>
                    <p id="car4" class="carText">Fashion Car 4,Model : 1976, Manual Transmission</p>
                    <p id="car5" class="carText">Fashion Car 5,Model : 1987, Manual Transmission</p>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Picture of the breakpoint
http://i61.tinypic.com/2076xx1.jpg

Code :

http://justpaste.it/ecjt

Comment: better create a jsfiddle to understand your problem

Comment: I have a problem with jsfiddle, but here it the code, just make a file.html and run it and you'll see the problem. http://justpaste.it/ecjt

Comment: Replace `pageshow` with `pageinit` and use delegation `.on("click"`. When the page is shown you bind another click event on the button resulting main multiple click events. `pageinit` fires once, hence, it attaches click event once only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pagehide you are setting the timeout right after clearing it. Also your code is more complicated than it needs to be.

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/apRh5/1/)**

NOTE: I commented out the localStorage bit as it is irrelevant to this issue.

myInterval is declared as global to the page (outside any function).
In picTimer you can hide all with one line of jQuery (`$(".jpg_move, .carText").hide();`)

```
var i=1;
var myInterval;

function picTimer()
{ 
    $(".jpg_move, .carText").hide();
    if(i>5) { i=1; }
    $("#car"+i).show();
    $("#img"+i).show();
    i++;
}

$(document).on("pageshow","#homepage",function() {    
    $("#trythisone").on("click", function() {            
            //if(localStorage.getItem("user") == null)
            //    return false;
            //else //Display pictures.
            //{            
                $(".jpg_move, .carText").hide(); //hide all cars
                $("#img1").show(); //First picture
                $("#car1").show(); //First car text
                myInterval  = setInterval(function(){picTimer()},3000);                
            //}
    });            
});    

//Stop interval
$(document).on("pagehide","#car_choose",function(){   
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    $(".jpg_move, .carText").hide(); //hide all cars
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare myInterval. Just above i=1; put the following:

```
var myInterval;
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint no clearInterval what value do you see for myInterval?

Comment: Hold your mouse over myInterval, and see what value comes up. Alternatively (To get the same information) you can click console at the top and type myInterval⏎ to see the value of the variable.